# CSS list-style-image

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I got a problem with CSS list-style-image tag my list image is some what large, and the text getting behind it is pushed down to the lower part of the style tag, is there a fix to bit it back in the middle

it is now like this:

```
|
|
| here
```

and I want to be:

```
|
| here
|
```

Comment: the | or below each one, some how they got messed up when I posted it :x

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question.  Can you explain it in better detail?  Actual code examples always help.

Answer (score 3):

Just increase the line-height of the li elements in question.

```
#iconlist li {
  line-height: 2em;
}
```

Also, as keithjgrant suggested, I would use background-images instead. List-images are positioned rather inconsistently in different browsers. So use something like this:

```
#iconlist li {
  padding-left: 22px;
  background: url(20x20-icon.png) left center no-repeat;
  line-height: 22px;
  list-style: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Forget setting the list style image and use the following css...

```
ul#example li {
    list-style-type: none;
}

/* create new marker */
ul#example li:before {
    display: marker;
    content: url("new_marker.png");
    /* set the following to fit your needs */
    vertical-align: 3px;
    padding-left: 2px;
    padding-right: 12px;
}
```

Note the vertical align style, set it to minus figures to push text upwards.

[Source of answer.](http://blog.janzikmund.cz/webdesign/list-style-image-positioning)

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a little unclear, but it sounds like you might need to look at background images rather than (or supplement to) list-style-images.

Answer (score 0):

The only realistic way to achieve this is with `background-image`:

```
ul li {
    background: transparent url(http://farm1.static.flickr.com/120/308863127_6eb1715f3b_m.jpg) 0 50% no-repeat;;
    list-style-position: outside;
    padding-left: 250px;
    line-height: 160px; /* vertical height of image */
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://www.jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/pWGH3/2/).

This does, however, [fail badly if the text of the `li` wraps to a second (or third) line](http://www.jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/pWGH3/3/).

Answer (score 0):

Try `vertical-align: middle;` (css)